# CSS Circle around a hyperlink

Tags: html, css

Is possible to create a big circle around a hyperlink using CSS?

I'm trying to achieve it but my circle is very small. I would like that circle size were similar to hyperlink size. If i put the hyperlink inside a div, it's not being centralized inside the circle.

Here is what i'm doing:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .circle {
        border-radius: 1000%;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px; 
        background: green;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" class="circle">Test test test test</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the `a` element is an inline element and thus accepts no height.  Change it to a block level element to give it a specified height:

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 100%;        
    background: green;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:100px;
}
```

To have the text appear in the middle, use `line-height` instead of `height`.

Working sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/7qfbopqj/

Comment: We can't always cater for older browsers.  IMHO, it's perfectly fine that older browsers miss out on cosmetic things such as rounded corners and stuff like that.

Comment: I'll render this code in backend and create an image from html. Perfect, buddy.

Comment: Helped me Dude!! THanks

Answer (score 1):

by using `padding` you can make the circle just bigger than the link

```
#circle {
    border-radius: 1000%;
    padding:50px;/* this instead of a set width and height just change this to change how much bigger the circle is than the link*/
    background:black;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put a div around the link and center the link within.

```
<div class="circle">
<center><a href="[link address]">[link name]</a></center>
</div>


.circle {
border: 2px solid red;
border-radius: 25px;
width: 10%;
height: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yg25us3k/

Comment: center tag?  Where are we, in the 1990s? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but you have to set the box size to match you text length, try this:

```
.circle {
    border-radius: 1000%;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px; 
    background: green;
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:40px;
    vertical-align:center;
    text-align:center;
    color:#ffffff;
}


<body>
    <a href="#" class="circle">Test </a>
</body>
```

try on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/prt4y7b2/